# Checking Independence for $\left\{\dfrac{1}{x^2+x-6},\dfrac{1}{x^2-5x+6},\dfrac{1}{x^2-9}\right\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is this subset of $V=\mathbb{F[0,1]}$ linearly independent, where the subset of $V$ is 
>   $\left\{\dfrac{1}{x^2+x-6},\dfrac{1}{x^2-5x+6},\dfrac{1}{x^2-9}\right\}$?

My work:

If this subset is independent, then $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$ must be the only solution for $\alpha\dfrac{1}{x^2+x-6}+\beta\dfrac{1}{x^2-5x+6}+\gamma\dfrac{1}{x^2-9}=0\\ \implies\dfrac{\alpha}{x^2+x-6}+\dfrac{\beta}{x^2-5x+6}+\dfrac{\gamma}{x^2-9}=0\\\implies \dfrac{\alpha}{(x+3)(x-2)}+\dfrac{\beta}{(x-2)(x-3)}+\dfrac{\gamma}{(x+3)(x-3)}=0\\$

I'm note sure how to proceed from this step (assuming what I've done so far is correct). A hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Multiply with $(x+3)(x-3)(x-2)$. That is not $\equiv 0$.

Comment: When you clear denominators, how many equations do you have, in how many unknowns?

Comment: Thanks, @DanielFischer. I don't know why that didn't occur to me. :)

Comment: So applying Daniel's hint gets me to: $\alpha (x-3)+\beta (x+3) + \gamma(x-2)$ means that the matrix will be $\begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\1&3\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\0&-6\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and since there is a zero row, the subset is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: checking that this set is linearly independent is equivalent to checking if the set 
$$\{x-3, x-2, x+3\}$$ is linearly independent.

Comment: ... and this requires that $2\ne 0$, $3\ne 0$, $5\ne 0$.